# Why are py and python giving different results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

Using py and [python](/questions/tagged/python) are giving me different results in the Command Prompt. For my specific program, when I run `python file.py`, the program works as expected. However, when I run `py file.py`, it gives me this error:

```
  File "wordcount.py", line 60
print(f"{wordlist[num]} {wordcount[num]}")
                                        ^
```

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Can anyone tell me why [python](/questions/tagged/python) works and not py?

EDIT: I should clarify, I've already checked the system. Typing py gives me Python 3.8.3, which means that the 2.x explanation doesn't match my case. import sys going into print(sys.version) gives me the same results.

Comment: Could you create a script with `import sys` and `print(sys.version)` and run that with Python and Py?

Answer (score 7):

Probably `py` is set to Python 2 and `python` is set to Python 3 on your system.

Try checking the versions with
`python --version` and `py --version` respectively.

It's not working with Python 2 since your code uses f-Strings, which where added in Python 3.6.

Answer (score 3):

it is because you are having two versions of python installed on your computer
when you run  `py [file.py]` it runs on python 2.x version when you run `python [file.py]` it runs on python 3.x version. 
You are using f-string's it is latest feature of the python so it won't run on python 2.x verison

just try checking version by typing `py --verion` and `python --version`